# I want to do an enqueue and dequeue for an array, but it shows that object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#-2.0

//first i declared the queue

```
int i = 2;
Queue[] Queue_points = null;
```

//then inside the constructor of the class i did the below line Where count =10

```
Queue_points=new Queue[count]
```

//when  the code below ids executed it shows object reference not set to an instance of an //object

```
Queue_points[i].Enqueue(value);
```

//want to know if this method is possible and if no pls do suggest any other method

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Please use the preview to see what your question looks like. You can omit the comment-style using `//` and just type your question.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this question doesn't deserve one. You didn't dedicate a minimal effort to even clean up your question as @ThomasW. suggested. If you show no interest in the question, noone else should.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating an Array of Queue. Instead you should create a queue and Enqueue/Dequeue from it as

```
Queue<object> queue = new Queue<object>();
queue.Enqueue(value);

object value = queue.Dequeue();
```

---- or as per your code, you can initialize each queue ----

```
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    Queue_points[index] = new Queue<object>();
```

and then use Enqueue or Dequeue